# How to change the login function in ASP.Net web application template?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project that is using the web application template in VS 2015. I want to change the login function so that the authentication process will use the private database, but I have had a hard time understanding the code.

The following is the **origin code** (I have coded to use the private database for the login function, but it failed to keep the login status):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Account
{
    public partial class Login : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
            // Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
            //ForgotPasswordHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Forgot";
            OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
            }
        }

        protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user password
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                        Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          true);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UserManager should have an underlying DbContext associated with it. You can change the connection string name associated with that context.